# Migrate OsCommerce in to Magento

Tags: magento, oscommerce

How can I start OsCommerce migration to Magento?

Comment: sounds like a reasonable question, why the downvote?

Comment: Voted up, because question is good.

Answer (score 4):

[Here is the official extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Magento+Core/extension/114/os-commerce-import) for this purpose.

Comment: it is not working for magento 1.4